# To make HTML 5 Datepicker work on mozilla

Tags: html

I have a HTML 5 datepicker in my bootstrap modal popup.It works on chrome but not in mozilla is there any possiblity to work in mozilla and IE.

```
<input type="date style="width:50%" name="nmdob" id="iddob"  class="form-control "/>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in your syntax.

A quote `"` was missing after `type="date"`.

```
<input type="date" style="width:50%" name="nmdob" id="iddob" class="form-control">
```

You can use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) or a [linter](https://github.com/mozilla/html5-lint) to ensure mistakes like this do not occur.

Comment: Is there any possibility in IE

Comment: My suggestion should fix the issue in IE.